# Adding Hover Text (R Plotly Map)

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I want to add hover text to this map (from ~IntZoneName) but just can't find a way.
Am I correct to be using scatter?
I'm using spatial files which I've joined with a dataframe and then using Plotly to make graph interactive.  Currently hover is just displaying data from ~CrudeRate7DayPositive.

```
plot_ly(map_x,
        type = "scatter",
        color = ~CrudeRate7DayPositive,
        colors = cols,
        text = ~IntZoneName, 
        hoverinfo = "text",
        alpha = 0.8) %>% 
        layout(title = "Crude Rates")
```

[image: Screen shot of map]

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on plotly and went with ggiraph which did everything I wanted

```
gg <- ggplot(map_x) +
  geom_sf_interactive(aes(fill = CrudeRate7DayPositive, 
                          tooltip = c(paste0(IntZoneName, "\n",CrudeRate7DayPositive,  " cases per 100,000 \n (7 Day Crude Rate)")),  
                          data_id = IntZoneName)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Purples") +
  theme_void()
x <- girafe(ggobj = gg)
x <- girafe_options(x,
                    opts_zoom(min = 0.7, max = 2) )
if( interactive() ) print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, a simple 'typo' was the cause; I noticed the difference between these references: [1](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/04/visualizing-geo-spatial-data-with-sf-and-plotly/) and [2](https://plotly-r.com/maps.html#cartograms). It appears `hoveron='fill'` vs. `hoveron='fills'` makes all the difference, depending on what version you are on I suppose.

Plotly reference also helps for ground truth... https://plotly.com/r/reference/